# How to link XAML file to Xamarin.form Previewer

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, preview

How do I connect `XAML` file to Xamarin.form Previewer

as you can see this `XAML` file not linked to previewer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/#Adding_Design-Time_Data), you will need to assign some static data to your view for the Previewer when using Bindings. You can do so by assigning a static data context. James Montemagno has already described how to do so [here](http://motzcod.es/post/143702671962/xamarinforms-xaml-previewer-design-time-data).

If that doesn't solve the issue at hand, then Xamarin is already aware that [some issues may exist](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/#Troubleshooting) since the Previewer is still only in preview:

> - Project should be built (compiled) before attempting to preview XAML files.
> - The Designer Agent must be set-up the first time you preview a XAML file - a progress indicator will appear in the Previewer, along with progress messages, until this is ready.
> - Try closing and re-opening the XAML file.

If the solutions as mentioned above doesn't solve the issues you experience, I would recommend that you [get in touch with Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com). As mentioned, the Previewer is still in preview, so issues may still exist.